# What types of bluetooth devices exist?

Tags: linux, bluetooth, device

I'm using **bluetoothctl** to check for device type (I need it to choose the right icon for the bluetooth device). I have found that so far exists **phone** and **audio-card**. Do you know where to find a list of all those types of bluetooth devices?
This is the output from bluetoothctl, and there is a field with **Icon**. All posible types from that field is what I'm interested in.

> Device XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX (public)
>
> Name: XXXXX
>
> Alias: XXXXX
>
> Class: 0x00240408
>
> Icon: audio-card

Answer (score 2):

The answer to this can be found by browsing the source of the bluez bluetooth stack in [src/dbus-common.c](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/src/dbus-common.c).

At the time of writing this answer, the complete list is:

```c
"audio-card"
"audio-headphones"
"audio-headset"
"camera-photo"
"camera-video"
"computer"
"input-gaming"
"input-keyboard"
"input-mouse"
"input-tablet"
"modem"
"multimedia-player"
"network-wireless"
"phone"
"printer"
"scanner"
"unknown"
"video-display"
```

Comment: There is official list of bluetooth device classes https://bitbucket.org/bluetooth-SIG/public/src/main/assigned_numbers/core/appearance_values.yaml

source: https://www.bluetooth.com/wp-content/uploads/Files/Specification/Assigned_Numbers.pdf?id=3 (2.6.2 Appearance Category ranges)

Answer (score -2):

[image: Device icons]

With the help of **gtk3-icon-browser** I noticed that the Icon type from **bluetoothctl** corresponds with the theme-default icons.